# Instagram Insight API for page not linked to FB page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to get Instagram insights via API (or sdk) for a page that is not linked to a facebook page?

From what I have read on the link [Instagram Insight API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview) it says

> However, unlike Facebook users, Instagram users cannot grant your app access tokens directly. Instead, they must connect their Instagram Professional account to a Facebook Page. Once connected, any Facebook User who is able to perform Tasks on behalf of that Page will be able to grant your app a User access token, which you can then include in API requests..

Is there no way to get insights via API for pages that are not linked to facebook page? Cant the Instagram account grant an access key or something along the line ?

Comment: What about “cannot” and “must” seems ambiguous to you?

Comment: Says on that very same page, _“The API can only access data in Instagram Professional accounts that have been connected to a Facebook Page.”_, and _“Instagram Professional accounts must be connected to a Facebook Page before their data can be accessed through the API.”_